# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object, javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Exception from Finished function when I run it: TypeError: Undefined or null cannot be converted to object,
It gives this error, I couldn't find why it was caused or on which line, thanks for your help

Exception from Finished function when I run it: TypeError: Undefined or null cannot be converted to object,
It gives this error, I couldn't find why it was caused or on which line, thanks for your help

```
 try {
   fetch("https://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml")
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((data) => {
   const parser = new DOMParser();
   const xml = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
   const jsonData = xmlToJson(xml);
   const currencyData = jsonData.Tarih_Date.Currency;
   currencyData.forEach(async (doviz) => {
       await db.collection("currencies").add({
         name: doviz.CurrencyName,
       });
   });
 })


 } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
 }
```

My method to convert xml to json

```
function xmlToJson(xml) {
 var obj = {};

if (xml.nodeType == 1) {

  if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
    obj["@attributes"] = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
      var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
      obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
    }
  }
 } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) {
   obj = xml.nodeValue;
}

var textNodes = [].slice.call(xml.childNodes).filter(function(node) {
  return node.nodeType === 3;
 });
 if (xml.hasChildNodes() && xml.childNodes.length === textNodes.length) {
   obj = [].slice.call(xml.childNodes).reduce(function(text, node) {
    return text + node.nodeValue;
  }, "");
 } else if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
 for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
   var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
   var nodeName = item.nodeName;
   if (typeof obj[nodeName] == "undefined") {
     obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
   } else {
     if (typeof obj[nodeName].push == "undefined") {
       var old = obj[nodeName];
       obj[nodeName] = [];
       obj[nodeName].push(old);
     }
     obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
   }
 }
}
return obj;
}
```

Comment: The error is not in the conversion. It is either an error in the FETCH (CORS) or in the add (fireStore)

Comment: There is another method. I am saving the json data there in firestore database, there is an error in my method above, which line should I find?

Comment: Remove everything and make an array with 3 lines and store those. If that works, add code